# Schedule Auto Shutdown of resources in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to schedule auto start or stop resources(EC2 Instances) for specific timings on AWS.
Is there an API to do the same ?

Comment: This is very broad, I think the question should be AWS/Asure not both. You also need to specify what resources you want to shutdown. AKS, EKS, VMS etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to put automation for start and stop a particular set of or a particular ec2 instance now this is possible using AWS System Manager you can do a lot more. I would strongly recommend to check out the official documentation it helped me sure it will help you as well [AWS System Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html)

You can also set up a Lambda function to start and stop EC2  [AWS Setup a Lambda to Start and Stop EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/)

Please let me know if you need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of Lambda and CloudWatch.

Please refer: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Comment: Why you need a Lambda function explicitly when you have AWS System Manager And When we support automation over the cloud going with managed services will be a wise decision I did it using Lambda function for Snapshot Start-Stop patching etc but that time there was no such Services like AWS System Manager.

Comment: Hello Prabhat,

Thank you for sharing your views.

There are some scenarios, in which we cannot make the Instance as managed, this may be due to any reason, for example, let's say you do not have access to ssm endpoints, then the Instance will not come up as managed. In such scenario it is easy to use Lambda function and use CloudWatch Events to schedule the stop/start of your Instance.

Comment: I would Suggest we should recommend a suggestion as per the question talking SSM or Lambda all need role /policy to communicate with API action/endpoints as the User doesn't mention anything related to access.  And We are suggesting him to create a lambda function to start and stop and what if he has no idea about lambda serverless and perhaps not into coding so, discussing on Assumption is not considered as a solution. Ideally, we should make it Short Simple Crispy. Thanks .

Comment: Still I recommend this as well https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Comment: @PrabhatSingh the last link you shared above is following a similar approach as this answer

Answer (score 0):

We are using the instance scheduler stack. You can easily create a cloudformation stack then use tags to define which and when the instances need to stop and started.

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/architecture.html